# How to change the NaCl toolchain?

Tags: google-chrome, midi, google-nativeclient

I am trying to build a native client module that uses the [improv](http://improv.sapp.org/) lib to receive midi input directly in the web browser.
But I have run into problems as the headers of the improv like termio.h, and sys/ioctl.h and more: a lot of header files that is not present in the newlib toolchain.

My question is, how do I change the toolchain to be used in my toolchain such that it uses the linux_x86 instead of the default linux_x86_newlib toolchain?

[The wikipedia page on the Native Client](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Native_Client) says "Native Client uses Newlib as its C library, but a port of GNU libc is also available." and I see the toolchain in the pepper_1/toolchain folder, but how do I tell the build.scons script to use this alternative toolchain?

Thanks to anyone that can bring some lights to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native Client modules do not have the ability to access MIDI input.

The level of access to local resources is (intentionally) greatly limited:  core NaCl only provide the ability to allocate memory, create threads, and use a simple IPC mechanism, and the stable API exposed by the Integrated Runtime (IRT) doesn't expose the IPC syscalls, but rather exposes the Pepper interface to access browser-side resources.  The Pepper interface is intended to only give NaCl module access to the same kind of resources that JavaScript have -- so that using a NaCl module wouldn't introduce any new security vulnerabilities (via resource access) that weren't already present.  Thus far, this means WebFS storage, DOM event notifications, etc, and notably does not include general USB device access nor MIDI access.  Given this, I suspect that until the web platform permits JavaScript to access MIDI, it will be unlikely that Native Client would have access.